# Dynamic input field to calculate an invoice total

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am trying to create a simple calculation function and because of my lack of JS skills I just do not why it isn't working. The best I could get for now is a working 'calculate price' and a not working 'calculate total'. What I get from 'calculate total' is a result of 0.00 no-mater what the input is. So this is  the JS I've got:

```
    //Calculate price
$("#amount").live('click',function() {
    var $itemrow = $(this).closest('.cust_row');
    $quantity = $itemrow.find('#itemQty').val();
    $price = $itemrow.find('#product_price').val();
    $result = $quantity * $price;
    $result = $result.toFixed(2);
    $itemrow.find('#amount').val($result);
});

//Calculate total
$("#total").live('click',function() {
    var $itemrows = $(this).closest('#invoice_items');
    $price = parseFloat($itemrows.find('.amount').val());
    $total = 0.00;
    for (i = 0; i < $price.length; i++)
    {
        $total += parseFloat($price[i].value);
    }
    $result = parseFloat($total).toFixed(2);
    $itemrows.find('#total').val($result);
});
```

and the html bit:

```
<div id="invoice_items">

            <div class="cust_row">
                    <div class="cust_row_40"><strong>Product Name</strong></div>
                    <div class="cust_row_30"><strong>Category</strong></div>
                    <div class="cust_row_10"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
                    <div class="cust_row_10"><strong>Price</strong></div>
                    <div class="cust_row_10"><strong>Amount</strong></div>                
            </div>
            <div class="cust_row">
                    <div class="cust_row_40"><input name="product_name[]" class="input_tbl" id="product_name" tabindex="1"/></div>
                    <div class="cust_row_30"><input name="category_name[]" class="" id="category_name"  readonly="readonly" /></div>
                    <div class="cust_row_10"><input name="itemQty[]" class="itemQty" size="4" id="itemQty" tabindex="2"/></div>
                    <div class="cust_row_10"><input name="product_price[]" class="product_price" size="5" id="product_price" readonly /></div>
                    <div class="cust_row_10"><input name="amount[]" class="amount" id="amount" size="5" readonly  /></div>                
            </div>
            <div class="clear_b"></div>
            <a href="#" id="addRow" class="button-clean large"><span> <img src="../img/icon-plus.png" alt="Add" title="Add Row" /> Add Item</span></a>

            <div style="text-align: right;">Total: <input name="total[]" class="" id="total" size="5" readonly  /></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but for some reason the html didn't post.

Comment: knockout.js is great for this kind of thing checkout http://knockoutjs.com/ and http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/adNuR/

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = parseFloat($itemrows.find('.amount').val());
```

You're not going to get a list from that - parseFloat only parses one float, despite it looking like you're expecting several $itemrows.

Instead of this:

```
$price = parseFloat($itemrows.find('.amount').val());
$total = 0.00;
for (i = 0; i < $price.length; i++)
{
    $total += parseFloat($price[i].value);
}
```

Try this:

```
<div id="invoice_items">

        <div class="cust_row_labels">
        <!-- I changed this... -->
```

so we dont grab it accidentally when trying to get total calculation. There are other ways to go about this but this was easiest.

```
// Given a "cust_row", calculate a price
function calcPrice( $cust_row ) { 
    // The $ in cust_row is a -loosely- defined way
    // indicating something is a "jQuery wrapped" element
    // (not a js coding thing, but more of a jQuery ease of use thing)

    // Below I'm taking your price calculating code and making it
    // more reusable

    var quantity = $cust_row.find('#itemQty').val();
    var price = $cust_row.find('#product_price').val();
    var result = quantity * $price;

    return result.toFixed(2);
}

// We can now use that function whenever, not just when "#amount" is clicked
// but we still have to tie them #amount and the method back together somehow
$("#amount").live( "click", function() {
    var $theAmount = $( this ),
        $customerRow = $theAmount.parents( ".cust_row" );
    $theAmount.val( calcPrice( $customerRow ) );
} );


// function for finding all totals
function overallTotal() {

    var total = 0;

    $( "#invoice_items .cust_row" ).each( function() {

        total += calcPrice( $( this ) );
        // "this" is a weird moving target, in this case
        // its each cust_row as we cycle through them
    } );
```

etc...

Your variables don't need to start with dollar signs, ie: I used prices instead of $prices, and $total could just be total (assuming you are consistent throughout whichever you choose). You probably saw that often because of jQuery examples, but people tend to use $ as a shorthand to indicate that its a jquery thing you're dealing with.

Also, it seems as if - given the presence of something called "add row", you'll want to append more cust_row things in here, but you may run into problems given that some things are IDs. An ID should be unique on a page - once you add another row you'll have more than one thing with an ID of amount. Change those ids to classes, then rewrite the appropriate selectors to start with . instead of #

Comment: It does make sense when you're saying it! Thanks for the good answer. I've managed to get the value of the first input only, which is a progress comparing to nothing. I've got this so far:

Comment: $("#total").live('click',function() {
 var $itemrows = $(this).closest('#invoice_items');
 var prices = [];
 $itemrows.each( function() {
     prices.push(parseFloat($(this).find('.amount').val()));
 });
 $total = 0.00;
 for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
 {
  $total += prices[i];
 }
 $result = $total.toFixed(2);
 $itemrows.find('#total').val($result);
});

Comment: Going to update my answer given my clearer understanding of where you are and your markup (i kinda skimmed earlier) o:) Fyi: you can also edit your question to show what the code currently looks like instead of posting it in a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

`$price = parseFloat($itemrows.find('.amount').val());`

Isn't this parsing a float out of an array of your inputs? If you remove that, you should be able to loop through your inputs, and the parse float inside the loop will be enough.

`$price = $itemrows.find('.amount').val();`